# How can i get a more precise battery level?

Tags: java, android, performance, power-management, batterylevel

I already saw a lot of questions of this kind but the answers aren't what i am looking for, so i will try to be "precise" as well.

I already know about `intent.getIntExtra("level")` && `intent.getIntExtra("scale")`, i am using it, it works but for analysis it's not good enough, it just gives a simple int, and if i convert it to percentage it still being an int. I need to get more a more detailed value. I already saw about `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER`, that could do what i need but it's not compatible with my device, as i can only read `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY`.

So my question is: Is there any work around, or some other solution that can get me the actual battery level? A level with some decimals that can be used in a graph or analysis.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't need decimals to build a graph or analysis.  You are confusing precision and accuracy, which are not the same thing.  Adding decimals is more precise, it is not necessarily more accurate.

Comment: ok. Still think i need if i want to get a graph that matters. Because im getting some device stats overtime and need to see the actual battery draining associated with some equipment that is being connected. anyway, I did say "precise" wasnt even talking about accuracy because it is already hard enough to get those decimals. But thank you anyway

ps: Luis Muñoz thank you for editing

Comment: You're assuming the device is accurate to more than 2 digits of precision. It really isn't, especially when you consider the full life cycle of a battery (discharge characteristics differ over time and usage).

Comment: ok i see what you mean. I think that with `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER` i could get more precision/accuracy but it's not available for what i saw. That's the reason of this post. To get another idea or solution for this problem.